# how to switch to SQL server state for sessions.... I get an error

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

Because of some In Proc problems I try to switch to SQL State session.

I checked my CMS database and I see the tables like aspnet_XXX already exists. To be sure I also created the DEFAULT database "aspnetdb" and  compared the tables aspnet_xxx  and checked whether they already exists in my CMS_DB_DEV or not... and all of them are already exists.

Then I went to web.config and I configured via IIS the sessionstate connectionstring and it looks like below:

```
  <system.web>
      <sessionState allowCustomSqlDatabase="true" 
                    cookieless="UseCookies" mode="SQLServer"   
                    sqlConnectionString="Server=localhost;Database=cms_db_dev;User ID=sa;Password=xxxx" 
                    timeout="20" />
```

now when I run my application I get the error:

> Unable to use SQL Server because ASP.NET version 2.0 Session State is
>   not installed on the SQL server. Please install ASP.NET Session State
>   SQL Server version 2.0 or above.

I use W7 pro, IIS 7.5 is installed

I checked these 2 links which mention the problem but no hope:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317604

http://www.brianstevenson.com/blog/aspstate-concurrently-running-for-net-1011-and-net-20#comment-984

AFter I get this working on my localhost, I'll do the same in Production machine. It seems the tables already exists, so I just need to configure web.config....

I MAY NOT DELETE THE EXISTING tables (like aspnet_xxx), because it's used by Dotnetnuke CMS system... But I can test on my localhost...

so what am I missing ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like the production environment has perhaps only the 1.1 versions of the DB structures you need.  You can run the 2.0 aspnet_regsql.exe with the -ssadd flag and appropriate arguments to create the newer version.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229862(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: I ran "aspnet_regsql -ssadd -E" and got start adding session.... Finished... but still get the same problem.

Comment: Agreed - aspnet_regsql should solve your problem.  -E indicates the currently logged in user will be used to create the db assets - perhaps you need to ensure your web app's identity or connection string user has access to the newly created tables...

Comment: Why do you have "AllowCustomSqlDatabase=true"?  When you run regsql_iis.exe are you specifying the SQL server on which you want to install via the -S flag?  As an alternative, you may want to check out the InstallSqlState.sql script and/or the InstallPersistSqlState.sql script.

Comment: You may need to specify an "initial catalog" in your connection string or remove "AllowCustomSqlDatabase=true".

Comment: when I run "InstallSqlState" it says run aspnet_regsql and do not manually run this script. I have specy allowcustomsqldatabase because I'm not using default database which is"aspnetdb". that's what I read in the links I've sent above in my issue.

Comment: @mikey: if I remove allowcustomsqldatabase and use "initial catalog" or "database" I get this error:  The sqlConnectionString attribute or the connection string it refers to cannot contain the connection options 'Database', 'Initial Catalog' or 'AttachDbFileName'. In order to allow this, allowCustomSqlDatabase attribute must be set to true and the application needs to be granted unrestricted SqlClientPermission. Please check with your administrator if the application does not have this permission.

Comment: So then set your initial catalog in your connection string, to the name of the database you've configured.

Comment: You want allowcustomsqldatabase=true AND in your connection string you want Initial Catalog=<yourcustomdbname>;

Comment: @mikey: It's not clear. The aspnet_xx tables are already in CMS_DB_Dev...  please clarify what you want me to do?

Comment: @mesut let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1797/discussion-between-mikey-and-mesut)

Comment: info from Mike: we created a new database cms_session, then run C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727>aspnet_regsql -S localhost -U sa 
-P xxx -ssadd -sstype c -d cms_session 

solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of points:

1. The **SQL Session** tables have names starting with `ASPState`, not `aspnet` - those are for the various provider stores (membership, roles, profiles, etc).
2. If you run aspnet_regsql with -ssadd command, it will by default create a Database called "ASPState" with some stored procedures in it, and use TempDB for the actual persistance.

To use your existing database, you would need to run:

```
aspnet_regsql -ssadd -sstype c -s LocalHost -d cms_db_dev -u sa -P XXXXX
```

This will:

- `-ssadd` Add support for SQLServer Mode session state to the Sql Server specified with the `-s` option
- `-sstype c` Create a custom persisted session state database, where both the data and the stored proc's are stored in the same database (as opposed to `p` which would store everything in a database called `ASPState`, or `t` which will create the stored proc's in the `ASPState` database but store the data in TempDB).
- `-s Localhost` (or `-s .\`) Use the local database instance, update as needed.
- `d cms_db_dev` The name of the custom database to add the tables and stored proc's to.
- `-u sa -P XXXXX` Valid credentials to create the database, could probably use `-E` to use windows credentials if on LocalHost.